# Remote running of python file X11 issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, remote-server, x11-forwarding

i'm using remote-ssh VSC extension to run python files from windows on remote Ubuntu VPS

The problem is, i cant run code with tinkter or some commands like `xeyes`
They seems running, but there is no window displaying the result appearing.

What should i look at Local and server sides to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I need to run Xming on local machine in parallel with vscode. This way xming open window with graphic content in it